# How can you avoid lots of os.pardir in a row when constructing upward paths using os.path.join?

Tags: python, python-2.7, path, filesystems

I'm trying to avoid this kind of thing:

```
sibling_location = os.path.join(leaf_dir, os.pardir, os.pardir, os.pardir, sibling_name)
```

I thought it would be cool to say

```
sibling_location = os.path.join(leaf_dir, *[os.pardir]*3, sibling_name)
```

but unfortunately that `*` argument expansion trick doesn't allow further arguments after the list it expands.

Comment: unrelated: the syntax works on Python 3.5, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: cool - makes sense that it should :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heh - found a way.

```
sibling_location = os.path.join(leaf_dir, *([os.pardir]*3 + [sibling_name]))
```

It doesn't read wildly well, but it is concise.   Happy to accept other better answers :)

Answer (score 2):

How about using [`pathlib2`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pathlib2/) (backport of Python 3 standard library module [`pathlib`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html))?

```
>>> leaf_dir = '/path/to/some/deep/deeper/leaf_dir'
>>> sibling_name = 's'
>>> 
>>> # Using os.path.join
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join(leaf_dir, *([os.pardir]*3 + [sibling_name]))
'/path/to/some/deep/deeper/leaf_dir/../../../s'
>>> os.path.normpath(os.path.join(leaf_dir, *([os.pardir]*3 + [sibling_name])))
'/path/to/some/s'
>>>
>>> # Using pathlib / pathlib2
>>> import pathlib2
>>> str(pathlib2.Path(leaf_dir).parents[2] / sibling_name)
'/path/to/some/s'
```

Comment: Nice.  Is pathlib2 guaranteed available, or do I have to install it?

Comment: @GreenAsJade, You should install it in Python 2.x. built-in in Pytohn 3.4+.

Comment: Thx.  Great solution where this is possible.  Unfortunately, I have a situation where I can't add libraries (long story :) )